# Run PLay Framework 2.x in IntelliJ IDEA using SBT task auto stop server

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I try to run Play project in IntelliJ IDEA. i follow this [document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/IDE#IntelliJ-IDEA).

this is my config. **api** is my sub project[image]

But when I hit run icon, my service start successful and immediately `AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server`. then I type `api/run` in *sbt shell*, my service start successful and work normally. this issue only happen when I check **User sbt shell** in config

this is my log in sbt shell

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe" -server -Xmx1536M -Dsbt.supershell=false -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsbt.version=1.3.8 -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar C:\Users\LAP13556-local\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar early(addPluginSbtFile=\"\"\"C:\Users\LAP13556-local\AppData\Local\Temp\idea979.sbt\"\"\") "; set ideaPort in Global := 51722 ; idea-shell"
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\LAP13556-local\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading settings for project crm-server-build from plugins.sbt,idea979.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\...\crm-server\project
[info] Loading settings for project crm-server from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to crm-server (in build file:/C:/Users/.../crm-server/)
[info] Defining Global / ideaPort
[info] The new value will be used by Compile / compile, Test / compile and 3 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to crm-server (in build file:/C:/Users/.../crm-server/)
[IJ]sbt:crm-server> api/run

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping server...

[success] Total time: 26 s, completed Jul 31, 2020 9:26:28 AM

[IJ]sbt:crm-server> api/run // I type this command

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Can anyone tell me the reason. Thank you.